# Independent coloring of contour and 3D plot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, gnuplot

I have a problem with pgfplots where the addition of a contour plot at the bottom of a 3D plot changes the coloring of the surface plot. This is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\zmin{-6}
\def\zmax{8}

\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
             [
                 zmin=\zmin,
                 zmax=\zmax,
             ]
             \addplot3[
                 contour gnuplot={
                     output point meta=rawz,
                     number=20,
                     labels=false,
                 },
                 domain=-5:5,
                 y domain=-5:5,
                 samples=20,
                 z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{\zmin}
             ]
             {%
                 min(x+y, \zmax)
             };
             \addplot3[
                 surf,
                 samples=20,
                 domain=-5:5,
                 y domain=-5:5
             ]
             {%
                 max(min(x+y, \zmax), 0)
             };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example turns out like this:
[image: Example image with contour]

Without the contour, the resulting image is:
[image: Example image without contour]

What I would like to have is an image with the contourplot, but using the coloring of the surfplot as it is shown in the image without the contourplot. Any help is greatly appreciated.